# How can i set the spinner value to null

Tags: java, android

I have a spinner , then i want to set the first value to null. Which i will get the value of itemselected then send to the url. My problem is even though i didn't click it has value.
this is my spinner:

```
  public void addListenerOnSpinnerItemSelection() {
    spinner1 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
    spinner2 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner2);
    spinner3 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner3);
    spinner4 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner4);
spinner1 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
spinner1.setOnItemSelectedListener(new MyOnItemSelectedListener());
spinner2 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner2);
spinner2.setOnItemSelectedListener(new MyOnItemSelectedListener());
spinner3 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner3);
spinner3.setOnItemSelectedListener(new MyOnItemSelectedListener());
spinner4 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner4);
spinner4.setOnItemSelectedListener(new MyOnItemSelectedListener());
```

}
 this is my postdata:

```
         public void postData() {
// Create a new HttpClient and Post Header
HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("");
try {
    // Add your data

    List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
    nameValuePairs.add(new        BasicNameValuePair("dateSched",sharedpreferences.getString("currentdate", "currentdate")));
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("WeddingStyle", String.valueOf(spinner2.getSelectedItem())));
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("ColorMotif", String.valueOf(spinner3.getSelectedItem())));
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("LocationType", String.valueOf(spinner4.getSelectedItem())));
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("WeddingFlower", String.valueOf(spinner1.getSelectedItem())));
    httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

    // Execute HTTP Post Request
  HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

} catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
} catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
}
}
```

Comment: try to check prompt properties of Spinner.

Comment: prompt is not running to me.